# Convert subsequence of Collection to String

Tags: swift, generics, collections, sequence

I'd like to convert a SubSequence of a Collection to a String. For example, this function collects the first two bytes of the collection and converts it to a String.

```
func convert<T: Collection>(_ c: T) -> String 
    where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8 
{
    let start = c.startIndex
    let end = c.index(after: start)
    return String(bytes: c[start ... end], encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
}
```

This leads to this error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        return String(bytes: c[start ... end], encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                             ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Swift.Collection:167:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(position: Self.Index) -> Self.Iterator.Element { get }
           ^
Swift.Collection:189:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
           ^
Swift.Collection:25:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> Slice<Self> { get }
           ^
Swift.IndexableBase:54:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(position: Self.Index) -> Self._Element { get }
           ^
Swift.IndexableBase:63:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
           ^
Swift.Indexable:23:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(bounds: ClosedRange<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
           ^
Swift.Indexable:23:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(bounds: CountableRange<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
           ^
Swift.Indexable:45:12: note: found this candidate
    public subscript(bounds: CountableClosedRange<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
```

What am I missing here? :-)

Comment: You can simplify the body to `return String(bytes: c.prefix(2), encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: Sure. It was a simplified example to show the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, a `Collection`'s `SubSequence` is not guaranteed to have the same element type as the collection itself, which is due to a limitation of `associatedtype`s.

In fact, one of the motivations for [SE-0142: Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) is to allow the constraint `associatedtype SubSequence : Sequence where SubSequence.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element`, which would enforce this relationship.

Although in this particular case, as you're not utilising the `T.Iterator.Element == UInt8` constraint in the first place, you can constrain `T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element` instead (thanks @MartinR):

```
func convert<T: Collection>(_ c: T) -> String
    where T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == UInt8 {

    let start = c.startIndex
    let end = c.index(after: start)

    // please consider handling the case where String(bytes:encoding:) returns nil.
    return String(bytes: c[start ... end], encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
}
```

(In more general cases where you also need `T.Iterator.Element` constrained to a given type, you would want to add `T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element` as an additional constraint).

Comment: Was about to post the same :) – A single constraint `T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == UInt8` would be sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR Ah yes, you're quite right – thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: It was a simplified example that actually requires both constraints. Thanks for the explanation of both cases!